# how to find that which signal is received in perl?

Tags: perl, signals

I wrote a simple program for handling some of the signals.
My Program is,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{INT} = $SIG{TERM} = $SIG{HUP} = \&signal_handler;

sub signal_handler
{

print " ".localtime()." Handled the signal\n";

};

while(1)
{
  sleep(1);
}
```

What are the signals are specified in the `%SIG` hash that corresponds signal handler
will be called at the time of receiving the signal.
I declared one signal handler for three signals.

I want to find which signal is received.

In `C`, It will give the signal number by the signal handler arguments itself.

Example,

```
   void sig_handler(int signo);
```

I don't know in perl.I try to find that.But,I didn't find any answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The signal name (INT, TERM, etc) is passed as parameter to the signal handler. You could write for example:

```
sub signal_handler
{
    my $signal = shift;
    print " ".localtime()." Handled the signal $signal\n";
}
```